# Cloudformation security group set group name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

Using cloudformation SecurityGroup is possible set the GroupName or has to be provide by cloudformation?.

The final name format it´s pretty long and does not look nice, also is not a good match to use it for find it by command line.

I know I can use tags, but still don't understand why AWS don't allow us to add it, I guess because they´re lazy and they don't want to implement a validation.

Regards.

Comment: all i have to offer to this discussion is that setting a "GroupName" property to the CloudFormation resource does not reject the property itself, but simply fails the resource creation with an "already exists" error message... Need to find some time to look into how `terraform` supports this (if it does).

Answer (score 6):

You can set the name for a SecurityGroup by adding a Tag with the key "Name", like this:

```
"MySecurityGroup": {
  "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
  "Properties": {
    "GroupDescription": "Allow http",
    "SecurityGroupIngress": [
      {"IpProtocol": "tcp", "FromPort": "80", "ToPort": "80", "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"}
    ],
    "Tags": [
      {"Key": "Name", "Value": "MySecurityGroup"},
    ]
  }
},
```

Answer (score 3):

**[Updated Jun 26 2017]**
As of [Apr 28 2017](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/04/aws-cloudformation-adds-support-for-amazon-cognito-ebs-elastic-volumes-and-updates-resource-coverage/), it is now possible to specify a custom name for an EC2 Security Group using CloudFormation, using the [`GroupName`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group.html#cfn-ec2-securitygroup-groupname) property on the [`AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group.html) resource.

*Thanks surenyonjan for the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38095221/cloudformation-security-group-set-group-name/41305592#comment76507029_41305592) on this update.*

---

**[Original answer Dec. 23 2016]** -
No, it is not currently possible to provide a custom name for an EC2  Security Group using CloudFormation.

According to the [`AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group.html) resource documentation, there is no `Name` or `GroupName` property available. You can provide tags using the [`Tags`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group.html#cfn-ec2-securitygroup-tags) property as an alternative, as you pointed out.

Recently, some CloudFormation resources have started supporting custom names via a [`Name`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-apikey.html#cfn-apigateway-apigateway-apikey-name) property. A full list of supported resources is in the [Name Type](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-name.html) section of the documentation.

`AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup` is not one of the resources supporting custom names. As for why, presumably this is because this CloudFormation resource is an earlier implementation, created before custom names were supported by the service.

It's possible that AWS will eventually go back and update all of its existing CloudFormation resources with custom name support at some point, if enough users ask them to do so. If this is an important/critical feature for your use case, I'd recommend contacting their product/support teams with a feature request to help them make it higher priority.

Comment: if I am not wrong, CloudFormation does have property `GroupName` for resource [AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group.html). And there is only one valid AWS CloudFormation template version: `2010-09-09`. 
Please explain why your answer is No.

Comment: @surenyonjan thanks for the update on this resource. Note that CloudFormation resources are updated frequently, independently of the template version which has never changed. Refer to the CloudFormation [release history](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/ReleaseHistory.html) for the full history of updates to CloudFormation resources.

Comment: oh thanks. I only read this [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/format-version-structure.html) and I understood wrong that it was only one version

Answer (score 0):

The name of most resources is simply a type of special Tags with the Key **Name**, To edit this fields just add the tag to the template

```
  mySecurityGroup:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup'
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref myVPC
      GroupDescription: Security Group 
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 22
          ToPort: 22
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: mySecurityGroup
```